# How can i make my collisionplanes pick up more then 1 plane from a obj-file

Tags: c++, 3d, collision

Hello I'm new in making of 3d games and now I'm wondering how can I make this code store more collisionplanes. I've tried makin more then one collisionplane class and it did not work. So this code is in a if statement to check if it is a face and if it is a face and coll is true(coll is true if it finds a material named collision) then this code executes.

```
if(coll==true && collplane!=NULL)
            {
            sscanf(coord[i]->c_str(),"f %d//%d %d//%d %d//%d %d//%d",&a,&b,&c,&b,&d,&b,&e,&b);
            collplane->push_back(cPlane(normals[b-1]->x, normals[b-1]->y, normals[b-1]->z,
                                        vertex[e-1]->x, vertex[e-1]->y, vertex[e-1]->z,
                                        vertex[d-1]->x, vertex[d-1]->y, vertex[d-1]->z,
                                        vertex[c-1]->x, vertex[c-1]->y, vertex[c-1]->z,
                                        vertex[a-1]->x, vertex[a-1]->y, vertex[a-1]->z ));
            std::cout << "getting collisionplanes..." << std::endl;
            }
```

and then this.

```
cPlane::cPlane(float n1,float n2,float n3,
           float a, float b, float c,
           float d, float e, float f,
           float g, float h, float i,
           float j, float k, float l)
{
normal.change(n1, n2, n3);
p[0].change(a, b, c);
std::cout << p[0] << std::endl;
p[1].change(d, e, f);
p[2].change(g, h, i);
p[3].change(j, k, l);
}
```

note:if you are wondering anything please ask.

note:I'm ready to change this code if it helps, thank you.

Comment: Given the parameter names to `cPlane::cPlane`, do you think anyone will be able to help you?

Comment: Please elaborate how the title describes the question. The title made me expect some question on file format, dynamic data structures. The body (apart from being mostly unclear to me in total) does not seem to mention object files. It still does mention planes, but not in the context of reading and storing more than one of them (more than one of the same thing that is) but about making multiple classes, which seems to be a very different thing. I'd expect a question about deserialising multiple instances of the same collisionplane class. The whole `if` topic seems a new question...

Comment: ok sorry, for that cPlane is a class. So this first bit of code is in a if statement in obj-loader. So the if statement checks for f(faces) in the obj-file if it finds then it checks if it is a collisionplane that we determen by if the material is called collision. the sscanf gets the values and that are put in the collisionplane class that makes it into point p[0]... that i use to detect collision.

Comment: So the problem is that the faces go like:usemtl collision
s off
f 12/25/8 11/26/8 15/27/8 16/28/8
f 9/21/7 13/22/7 15/23/7 11/24/7
f 16/28/9 15/27/9 13/29/9 14/30/9
f 14/30/10 10/31/10 12/32/10 16/33/10
f 10/34/11 9/35/11 11/36/11 12/37/11
f 14/38/12 13/39/12 9/40/12 10/31/12  ::: but it only gets the this collision material becous i have to platforms(in the map this obj-file is) thos are the faces for the first but i don't now how i can get the second one.